# Bulk collect and forall with save exception

Tags: exception, oracle11g, save, forall, bulk-collect

I have the below code , emp1 table has data of 12 rows in which 2 empno's already present in emp table. i'm trying to save the exceptions for these 2 records and to insert remaining all to emp. But everything is getting error out and i couldn't able to insert into emp. Anyone please help.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  CURSOR C1
  IS
    SELECT EMPNO FROM EMP1;
TYPE T
IS
  TABLE OF C1%ROWTYPE;
  L_DATA T;
  L_ERRORS_COUNT NUMBER;
  EX_DML_ERRORS  EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (ex_DML_ERRORS, -47);
  L_ERRNO NUMBER;
  L_MSG   VARCHAR2(4000);
  L_IDX   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
  LOOP
    FETCH C1 BULK COLLECT INTO L_DATA;
    BEGIN
      FORALL I IN 1..L_DATA.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
      INSERT
      INTO EMP
        (
          EMPNO,
          ENAME,
          MGR
        )
        VALUES
        (
          L_DATA(I).EMPNO,
          'SCOTT',
          L_DATA(I).EMPNO
        );
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WHD');
      L_ERRORS_COUNT := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WHD::::'||L_ERRORS_COUNT);
      FOR J IN 1..L_ERRORS_COUNT
      LOOP
        L_ERRNO := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS
        (
          J
        )
        .ERROR_CODE;
        L_MSG := SQLERRM(-L_ERRNO);
        L_IDX := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(J).ERROR_INDEX;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I am here SVS:'||L_ERRNO||':'|| L_MSG||':'||L_IDX);
        --INSERT INTO EMPS_EXC1(SQLC ,SQLE ,INDX ) VALUES(L_ERRNO, L_MSG,L_IDX);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('I am here SVS:'||L_ERRNO||':'|| L_MSG||':'||L_IDX);
      END LOOP;
    END;
    EXIT
  WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;
END;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You would better tag your question with the DB you use.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0